# How to use a type on map operator in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

Basically, I am trying to use HttpClient instead of Http on all my calls, so I created an interface to be able to access some properties of the response, it is working fine for most of my calls; but the thing is that I have a typeahead with this code:

```
const URL = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json';
this.searchField = new FormControl();
this.results$ = this.searchField.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap(query => this.http.get(`${URL}?address=${query}`))
    .map(response => response)
    .map(response => response.results);
```

I tried to assign my interface called APIResponse to `response` on the last two lines, like this: `.map(response:APIResponse => ...)`, but it obviously throws a syntax error.

Where should I include the type for response? Or how could I change my code to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.http.get<ApiResponse>(...)`, then you can get rid of the `.json()` mapping. Didn't you read [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

Comment: Your tags say you're using a `HttpClient`, but the `json()` method is available when using `Http`. Which are you using? That is, what is the type of `this.http`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a type you need to use `()`:

```
.map((response:APIResponse) => ...)
```

Comment: This is a dangerous practice and should be avoided. The reason is that if the api is typed as `Observable <any>` this form gives a false illusion of type safety that can be broken at any time, especially with a chained operator call. Conversely, if the API has a proper parameter type, then explicitly specifying one is also a poor practice, because it again leads to misleading code.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd do:

```
.map(response => response.json() as ApiResponse)
.map(response => response.results);
```

BTW, if you were to use the new `HttpClient` introduced in angular 4.3, you wouldn't need to convert to JSON manually and could simply write:

```
this.httpClient.get<ApiResponse>(`${URL}?address=${query}`
    .map(response => response.results);
```